# pythonのライブラリーpytubeの使い方

Tags: python, python3

[pytube](https://github.com/nficano/pytube)の使い方を調べていて以下の記事を見つけたのですが、ここで使われているpytubeがドキュメントに載っていない使い方をしているのでどうなっているの教えて欲しいです。

[[Python] YouTubeからビデオをmp4形式でダウンロード](https://qiita.com/prs-watch/items/577544e19f87e8531e13)

```
from pytube import YouTube
from enum import Enum
import ffmpeg
import os
import re

class Loader(Enum):
    MP4 = 'mp4'
    WEBM = 'webm'

    def load(self, yt, res):
        vd = yt.get(self.value, res)
        vd.download('./videos')

def download(url):
    ext = 'mp4'
    res = ''
    exts = []
    yt = YouTube()
    yt.url = url
    for video in yt.videos:
        exts.append(video.extension)
        if video.extension == 'mp4':
            res = video.resolution
    if 'mp4' not in exts:
        ext = 'webm'
    ext = ext.upper()
    val = getattr(Loader, ext)
    val.load(yt, res)

def rename():
    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'videos')
    pattern = re.compile('(mp4|webm)$')
    files = os.listdir(path)
    for file in files:
        if pattern.search(file):
            file_path = os.path.join(path, file)
            new_file_path = file_path.replace(' ', '_')
            os.rename(file_path, new_file_path)

def convert():
    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'videos')
    pattern = re.compile('webm$')
    files = os.listdir(path)
    for file in files:
        if pattern.search(file):
            file_path = os.path.join(path, file)
            stream = ffmpeg.input(file_path)
            stream = ffmpeg.hflip(stream)
            stream = ffmpeg.output(stream, file_path.replace('.webm', '.mp4'))
            ffmpeg.run(stream)
            os.remove(file_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = input('url >> ')
    download(url)
    rename()
    convert()
```

for文の`yt.videos`この部分が自分の環境だとうまく動かないのですが、videosの部分はpytubeによるものなのでしょうか？
それとも他のライブラリーによるものでしょうか？

Comment: 「うまく動かない」だけではなく、より具体的な情報(エラーが出る等、実行した時の状況)を書いたほうが回答も付きやすいと思います。また、ライブラリはアップデートで挙動が変わるケースも考えられるので、参考にした記事の情報が古い可能性もあります。質問にもできるだけ使用したバージョンを含めておくとより親切です。

Comment: 添削して頂きありがとうございます。以後、気をつけます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ドキュメントに載っていない使い方

そもそも記事が古く、最新バージョンのpytubeが9.2.2であるのに対して記事の最終更新当時のものは7.0.18であり、すでにドキュメントと異なっているのが原因だと考えられます。

そこで、[公式リポジトリのREADME.rstの変遷](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/commits/master/README.rst)を確認したところ、
以下のコミットによりドキュメントから`.videos`の記述が消えたため、この前後に破壊的な仕様変更があったものと考えられます。
https://github.com/nficano/pytube/commit/deff05682b0567ff005f37adcb9b0af1583ada20#diff-88b99bb28683bd5b7e3a204826ead112

Comment: 年数がそこまでたっていなかったので変わっていないと考えていました。このように変わっていくのが普通なのですね。勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: [セマンティック・バージョニング](https://semver.org/lang/ja/) という慣例があり、おそらくこのライブラリはそれに従っているようです。そして、メジャーバージョンが7.x.xから9.x.xに変更しているため、当時のコードだと動かないだろうな、と考えるようにするのが（このライブラリに限らず）安全かもしれません。